# Hide selected element or DIV when clicked

Tags: html, hide, selected

I am looking for the simplest solution to this and I can't seem to get it right!

I have tried a number of combinations and nothing seems to work right, here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="hideme" onclick="hideme();">HIDE THIS DIV</div>

<script>
function hideme(this) {
this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

I want to do it in this way so that different div id's can be hidden easily

Comment: ok I have tried using onclick="hideme(this.id);"  not working yet but I feel like I'm on the right track!  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

**Here's how to do it using the `onclick` html attribute:**

html:

```
<div id="hideme" onclick="hideme(this)">HIDE THIS DIV</div>
```

javascript:

```
function hideme(element) {
    element.style.display ="none";
};
```

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uyw8w/6/)

---

**There are a few different ways to do this, here's one other way:**

html:

```
<div id="hideme">HIDE THIS DIV</div>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("hideme").addEventListener("click",
    function() {
        this.style.display ="none";
    }, false
);
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uyw8w/4/)

---

**Another way:**

html:

```
<div id="hideme">HIDE THIS DIV</div>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("hideme").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("hideme").style.display ="none";
    };
```

And the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uyw8w/2/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You just missed passing in the context to hideme:

```
<div id="hideme" onclick="hideme(this);">HIDE THIS DIV</div>
```

Then just reference the element directly and set its `display` to `none`

```
function hideme(ele) {
    ele.style.display = 'none';
}
```

[demo - jsBin](http://jsbin.com/OBOVAca/1/edit?html,js,output)